# Как найти одинаковые комбинации значений в массиве и заменить их на не повторяющиеся?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день. Прошу, помогите пожалуйста.

У меня есть конструктор массива:

```
import {uniqueId} from 'lodash';

const create = (x, y, value) => ({
x, y, value, id: uniqueId()
})

export {create}
```

Его я импортирую в этот компонент:

```
import {create} from './cellManager';

const initCells = () => {
    const cells = []
    for ( let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        const cell = create(getRandomCoord(), getRandomCoord(), i)

        cells.push(cell)
    }

    return cells
}

const getRandomCoord = () => {
    const randomCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3.9)
return randomCoord
}

export default initCells
```

У меня получается массив Cells со значениями `x`, `y`. Значение от 0 до 3. Данные значения служат координатами для отображения некоторых элементов. Я получаю эти значения рандомно, соответственно у меня в массиве есть одинаковые комбинации `x` и `y`.

Я хочу добиться чтобы было 16 неповторяющихся комбинаций чисел `x`, `y` от 0 до 3. То есть 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 1 3 и так до 3 3.

Comment: создай массив значений от 0 до 15, перемешай его случайным образом, перебери строки и ячейки в таблице которая 3 на 3 и для каждой клетки просто бери очередное значение из массива где 0..15 уже заранее перемешаны

Comment: Но почему `* 3.9`?

Comment: @Yaant, чтобы не 4 :-)

Comment: @Grundy Тетрафобия?

Comment: @Yaant, скорее ожидание что рандом возвращает [0,1], а не [0,1) :)

Comment: @Grundy К слову, любопытно, сколько раз за всю историю вызовов, `Math.random()` вернул точный 0? :)

Comment: @Yaant, вообще бывает

Comment: @Grundy Не сомневаюсь что бывает, оно ж еще и от реализации может зависеть, если там внутри какой-нибудь 16-битный ЛКГ, то вообще часто. :)

Comment: @Yaant Решил что так размах рандома больше будет) может я и не прав не знаю)

Comment: Ну тут проблема только в том, что в этом случае число `3` будет возвращаться на 10 процентов реже, чем `0`, `1` или `2`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getCells(x, y) {
  let a = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < x*y; i++) {
    a.push({i, val : Math.random()});
  }
  a.sort((a, b) => a.val - b.val);
  
  let getCoords = n => [n % x, (n / x) | 0];
  return a.map((el, i) => {
    let [x, y] = getCoords(el.i);
    return {x, y, value : i}
  })
};

console.log(getCells(4,4))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: Только единственное не могу понять до конца функцию getCoords, можете вкрации объяснить что там происходит, пожалуйста?

Comment: Там банально номер (от 0 до 15, в вашем случае) превращается в два числа - координаты в двумерном массиве. `0 -> [0,0], 3 -> [0,3], 4 -> [1,0], 15 -> [3,3]`... (`x` там - это число столбцов)

Comment: @Yannt [n % x, (n / x) | 0] в этом случае побитовое сравнение с 0 производится с 2 числами ? или с последним  (n / x)?

Comment: Не, тут нет никакого побитового сравнения, `num | 0` просто отбрасывает дробную часть у `num`. Эквивалентно `Math.floor(num)` для неотрицательных `num`, но короче. :)

Comment: Ну а вся запись целиком - это просто массив из двух элементов

Comment: @Yaarn все понял благодарю вас еще раз!

Answer (score 1):

самый элегантный способ, я думаю,
но это ES6

```
function getUniqValues(a) {
  return Array.from(new Set(a));
}
```

Comment: 1) Тогда уж `return [...new Set(a)]`; 2) `getUniqValues([{x : 1, y : 1}, {x : 1, y : 1}])` = ?